# Zoom world map in D3 upto particular level Around a given latitude and longitude

Tags: d3.js

Is there any way that I can focus into d3 world Map around a specific latitude and longitude on load of file.

Here is working plunker in which I can zoom around a d3 world Map.
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7LAvpItrt7IhQGPHEroW?p=preview)

Below code is used to zoom in for click.

```
function clicked() {
            currScale2 = projection.scale();
            if(beforeClickValue == 0)
            beforeClickValue = 150;
            beforeClickValue = beforeClickValue + 100;
            projection.scale(beforeClickValue);
            g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
 }
```

I need to zoom in near or around Kenya, if I provide a particular location in Kenya, eg:

```
    Latitude    0.55378653650984688  
    Longitude   35.661578039749543
```

Answer (score 2):

**If your centering point is determined by a feature**

If your point is a feature centroid, then you can automatically center your map using that feature:

There are a few ways to achieve this, one would be to set your projection to be centered on your features:

```
projection.fitSize([width,height],geoJSONKenyaTurkana);
```

fitSize takes the width and height of a bounding box - your svg - and sets the scale and translate of the projection to maximize the size of the features within that bounding box. .fitExtent will allow a bit more flexibility regarding margins:

```
projection.fitExtent([[10,10],[width-10,height-10]],geoJSONKenyaTurkana);
```

This will provide margins of 10 pixels: the first coordinate is the top left of the bounding box, while the second coordinate is the bottom right.

After setting your projection to be centered with either method, then you can append the features - your zoom constraints, however, will be relative to this starting point - as you have zoomed in on the projection. Here's a plunkr with this approach (using fitSize):

https://plnkr.co/edit/E7vqcwwISmmxUarCsWvw?p=preview

I've used your featureCollection as the feature, but you could center it on an individual feature in the feature collection.

---

Alternatively, and possibly more in line with your title, you can use a zoom identity to set the intitial zoom factor with d3.zoom, this manipulates the svg rather than the projection and uses your zoom function:

```
var bounds = path.bounds(geoJSONKenyaTurkana), 
dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0], 
dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

svg.call(_zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
  .scale(scale) 
  .translate(translate[0]/scale,translate[1]/scale)
);
```

This gives us something that looks like this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/CpL4EDUntz853WzrjtU0?p=preview

---

**If you want to manually set a centering point**

If however, you want to set your map to be centered according to a manually set point, you can accomplish this much the same way as above: modifying the projection, or modifying the zoom:

To modify the projection, you can use .center() which takes a coordinate and centers the map on this point:

`projection.center([longitude,latitude])`

Of course, points don't have area, so you will have to set the scale factor yourself, the value will depend on what you want to show:

`projection.center([longitude,latitude]).scale(k);`

Larger values are more zoomed in.

Alternatively, to manipulate the zoom function, we can use something like:

```
var x = projection([35.661578039749543,0.55])[0],
y = projection([35.661578039749543,0.55])[1],
scale = 20,  
translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

  svg.call(_zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
  .scale(scale) 
  .translate(translate[0]/scale,translate[1]/scale)
  );
```

As with setting the projection to center on a specific point, you'll need to set a scale value manually. Here I've arbitrarily chosen 20.

Comment: Hi I would like to use the last code snippet where we are providing the latitude and longitude value but using this am not able to zoom out using scroll and the stroke is very enlarged.I would like the output to be as in the first plunker and code similar to last snippet.

Comment: By scaling the svg elements their stroke will scale. You can update that on each zoom event to keep it steady: width = idealWidth/svgScale. In my last snippet I probably exceeded your zoom limit, disabling the scroll, you shoukd be able to fix that if you scale back a bit on load or alter the zoom extent